# writing a coin sorter program in python with no loops and reading from a text file

Tags: python

How Do I read from a file for a coin sorter program with a limit on an amount of coins?
Where do I go from this code?

```
total = float(raw_input("Enter the total purchase: "))
amount = float(raw_input("What amount is given: "))
bills = int(amount - total)
change = int(round(((amount - total) - bills) * 100))

quarters = change/25
change -= quarters * 25
dimes = change/10
change -= dimes * 10
nickels = change/5
pennies = change

print "Bills:", bills
print "Quarters:", quarters
print "Dimes: ", dimes
print "Nickels:", nickels
print "Pennies:", pennies
```

Where do I write in a file?

Comment: What are you expecting to be in this file?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: write in a text file of how many coins of each are in the sorter, then  being able to enter a change amount and then using the coins that can be used

Comment: and then check using if and then to see what change amount is needed

Comment: It's a good idea to use `//` for your truncating divisions instead of `/`, as the behaviour of `/` has changed for Python3